# Listfield focus issue in blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, focusable

I am using list-field in a BlackBerry application. In each list-field item, I have a bitmap-field at the left, text at center and again a bitmap-field at the right.
Can I determine whether the fields are focusable inside the list-field rows for keypad versions of BlackBerry Devices for e.g BlackBery Tour?

Comment: @MobileDev123 You're downvoting based on the author, not the question?  Are _you_ taking this community seriously?

Comment: @Michael this kind of question is not so great, i'm not sure about this forum but in blackberry's default forum this type of question is asked many times.

Comment: You asked a nearly identical question just a few days ago.  Did you look at, and learn from the responses there?   It seems not, since you still think a ListField row manages subfields.  Here's your original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092471/how-to-fire-an-event-for-different-fields-inside-list-field-item-in-blackberry

Comment: how to accept answer,can u tell me,as i am a newbie,i don't have much idea

Answer (score 0):

No in list field no control except whole row is focusable explicitly. If you want to perform any click events you can use `touchEvent()` but the calculation will be too complex and not so reliable.

If you want to have separate clickable items in one row you must use `HorizontalFieldManager` each time.

**Update:** : I have come across this scenario twice, and if I were in place of you I will consider what exactly the feature is about, If you are concerned about UI and there is not any heavy functionality behind focusing you can try `touchEvent` or `navigationClick` but using both will be cumbersome. Too much logic, too much thinking, hard to test.

If there is any functionality, you have an option to add them on menu, It will be more convenient way than using horizontal field manager or the above mentioned methods.

Comment: Thank u @MobileDev123 for the reply.Actually i am able to do the touchEvent for storm and its working with me,but my prob is with tour where touchEvent method is not supported.

Comment: I was concentrated on focusing, which is not possible in list row, you can try navigationClick method for all device. But again it matters on luck only..... I have come across this situation twice and have used horizontal field manager.